# Compacting Graph Labels stored in struct array in C

Tags: c, arrays, graph-theory

So I have structs like these:

```
typedef struct packed_edge {
    myint v0;
    myint v1;
} packed_edge;

typedef struct edge_list {
    packed_edge *list;
    myint edgeNum;
    size_t size;
} edge_list;
```

I basically have an array of packed_edge.

My goal is this: if I have pairs like these:

```
(1,3) | (1,8)  |  (2,7)  | (7,2) | (4,2)
```

I want them to become like this:

```
 (0, 1) | (0, 2) | (3, 4) | (4, 3) | (5, 3)
```

The pairs are edges of a graph, it is a function to compact labels. I want to use every number from 0 to |V|, which is the number of nodes, and only these ones, in an ordered way. I don't know if it is convenient to sort them first and then start working on it, and in truth I can't think of a good method to do this in the first place.
Any of you got any idea?

Comment: If you can use a node list instead of an array, then its easy to insert them in a sorted order.

Comment: @Murillio4 I think NodeList is more a thing for Javascript. I don't know if you meant linked lists, but I must use una array of number pairs.

Comment: Please explain the transform you show.  I can see (1,3) => (0, 1); then (1, 8) => (0, 2).  So far, so good.  However, you continue (2,7) => (1,3) and I'm now baffled — 2 hasn't appeared before, so it should be mapped to 3; similarly, 7 hasn't appeared before and should be mapped to 4.  Or am I completely misunderstanding what the mapping is attempting to do?  (So, I think the mapped codes should be (0, 1) | (0, 2) | (3, 4) | (4, 3) | (5, 3) — unless I'm completely misunderstanding what you're trying to do.). Whether or not I'm misunderstanding, please clarify how the mapping works.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes you are perfectly right, the correct mapping is the one that you showed. I'll edit the main post. Thank you.

Comment: Will you ever have a situation where the old node numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 23002341, 999922234? Or will the old node numbers be relatively under control? If the numbers are under control (more or less), you can use arrays indexed by the old node number. If the node numbers can be horribly arbitrary, you are probably forced to search a (sorted?) list of node numbers. If the number of node numbers is small (10 say), it won't matter much (whether you index or search, or if you do linear vs binary search); if the number of node numbers can be big (hundreds, or thousands) it's more important.

Comment: Regardless of the detailed answer to my 'will you ever have a situation' comment, the basic technique will be to have a 'list' of '(old_num, new_num)' pairs, so you can see whether the old number you're looking at is already in the list or not. If it's not in the list, then you add it (and its mapping). Now that it _is_ in the list, you simply return the mapping (the new_num corresponding to the old_num). Rinse and repeat till you're all done. A sorted array in order of old_num allows you to do binary searches. An unsorted array requires linear searches. Linear search will be OK to begin with.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes I've come to the same conclusion, I think I'll use a 2d array for the associations and try to keep it most organized as possible to favour research. Btw numbers are not under control.

Comment: If your numbers are arbitrary like @JonathanLeffler said, you should use a *Hash Table* or a *Binary Search Tree*.